# Como fazer o preenchimento automático de formulários com PHP?

Tags: php

Como criar um script para preencher formulários, colar textos, tudo automaticamente?

Existe um site na qual tem login e senha, quero que o script logue automaticamente e depois faça a postagem que era necessária com o texto que eu pre-defini, e o login e a senha também estão pre-definidos.

O que devo estudar pra fazer isso?

Obs.: Quero fazer um script que faça isso com quem se cadastrar. Por isso não pode ser plugin.

Comment: O sentido é testar os formulários?

Comment: O ideal seria você utilizar um SERVIÇO do site ao invés de tentar o que você propõe. Por motivo de segurança, todo site sério bloqueia qualquer tentativa de login automático por script dessa forma. Você nunca vai conseguir fazer isso no Stack Overflow ou em qualquer provedor de identidade do OpenID, por exemplo.

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem sua dúvida, mas vou tentar.

Quando um usuário se cadastra no site, você precisa que ele automaticamente já acesse o site (entre em uma página inicial de quem faz o login), é isso?

Comment: Qual o sentido do voto negativo? Faça um comentário.

Comment: @JoãoNeto Po cara, a sua pergunta em nenhum momento refletiu isso. Se tivesse informado essa informação desde o início poderíamos ter lhe orietando muito melhor.

Comment: Recomendo ler a a pergunta sobre [robôs em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11286/como-criar-um-robo-com-php?answertab=active#tab-top) aqui do Stack Overflow, caso queira automatizar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é criar um script, que envie um `POST` para o formulário em questão que você está preenchendo todos os dias.

Você pode deixar tudo já preenchido e apenas executar esse script todos os dias.

Mas por que você não tenta fazer isso pelo navegador? Acho que é mais fácil até para nós desenvolvedores.

Já usei esses dois programas para preencher formulários de forma automática, veja se algum é útil.

## Para Firefox: [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/web-developer/)

[image: Web Developer Toolbar]

## Para Chrome: [iMacros for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?utm_source=plus)

[image: iMacros for Chrome]

Respondeu?