# Como criar um robô com PHP?

Tags: php

Qual o melhor caminho para a criação de um Robô em PHP?

O objetivo desde robô, é acessar a uma URL, com login e senha, inserir dados em determinados campos, submeter estes dados, e interpretar o resultado em tela.

Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui, acho que vai encontrar tudo que precisa. [https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php)

Comment: A melhor linguagem para isso é C# Windows Form(Ou Qualquer outra .NET) pois você pode usar o objeto WebBrowser para navegar, fazer isso em PHP seria um terror.

Comment: Vc gostaria de construir um [web crawler](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robôs para buscar e interpretar informações em outras páginas é tambem são chamados de *web crawlers* ou *spiders*.

Se trata de scripts que realizam o seguinte processo:

1. Requisição para uma URL.
2. Armazenar o retorno obtido em uma variável.
3. Interpretar o retorno, isto é, realizar o parser do HTML.
4. Buscar as informações relevantes.
5. Realizar os processos com as informações obtidas.

O processo nos passos de 1 à 3 é facilmente resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
$url = 'www.exemplo.com';
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
```

Desta maneira você irá obter um objeto que lhe permitirá navegar em todo o HTML da maneira que for necessário.

Por exemplo, para pegar todos os links de uma página e exibir os endereços ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($anchors as $element) {
    $href = $element->getAttribute('href');
    echo $href . '<br>';
}
```

Uma classe interessante que pode auxiliar no tratamento do HTML e evitar milhares de linhas de código é a [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), e um tutorial ensinando como utilizar pode ser encontrado no site [Make Use Of](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-basic-web-crawler-pull-information-website/).

Para preencher simular que um formulário foi preenchido, basta fazer uma requisição para a URL que o formulário aponta utilizando o método de requisição esperado, isto é, requisitar URL presente no atributo `action` utilizando o método de requisição presente no atributo `method`.

Para simular a situação iremos alterar o código de requisição anterior para:

```
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    // Retorna o conteúdo como string
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.exemplo.com',
    // Nome de identificação do seu robô
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Nome do seu crawler',
    // Indica que a requisição utiliza o método POST
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    // Parâmetros que serão passados via POST
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        item1 => 'value',
        item2 => 'value2'
    )
));

// Fazendo a requisiçnao e salvando na variavel $response
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Finalizando o objeto de requisição
curl_close($curl);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');

// Realiza o parser da String de retorno da requisição
// Observe que o método mudou de loadHTMLFile para loadHTML
$dom->loadHTML($response);
```

[Saiba mais sobre o CURL](http://codular.com/curl-with-php)

Comment: Consegui criar o robot, usando Selenium Server + WebDriver, é bem completo, permite que se manipule todos os recursos de um navegador.